# WSO2 Data service not working for named queries (prepare statements)

Tags: wso2, esb, wso2-data-services-server, wso2-esb

I was just trying to do a simple data service connecting to HR schema on Oracle XE DB. I just wrote a simple query with operation which takes an input parameter and gets the result accordingly as per the bind data passed.

My Query looks as below

```
SELECT first_name,last_name,email,phone_number,hire_date,salary 
FROM employees 
WHERE first_name like :Bind_name
```

I have added a input variable Bind_name and passing it when im requesting the service.

But, when i trigger the service i see below error and couldn't find relevant help on web.

```
[2012-06-13 12:42:08,101] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.dataservices.core.description.query.SQLQuery} -  org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingPreparedStatement cannot be cast to java.sql.CallableStatement
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingPreparedStatement cannot be cast to java.sql.CallableStatement
    at org.wso2.carbon.dataservices.core.description.query.SQLQuery.setStringValue(SQLQuery.java:1943)
    at org.wso2.carbon.dataservices.core.description.query.SQLQuery.setParamInPreparedStatement(SQLQuery.java:1411)
    at org.wso2.carbon.dataservices.core.description.query.SQLQuery.createProcessedPreparedStatement(SQLQuery.java:1380)
    at org.wso2.carbon.dataservices.core.description.query.SQLQuery.processNormalQuery(SQLQuery.java:802)
    at org.wso2.carbon.dataservices.core.description.query.SQLQuery.runQuery(SQLQuery.java:2069)
    at org.wso2.carbon.dataservices.core.description.query.Query.execute(Query.java:252)
    at org.wso2.carbon.dataservices.core.engine.CallQuery.execute(CallQuery.java:185)
    at org.wso2.carbon.dataservices.core.engine.CallQueryGroup.execute(CallQueryGroup.java:110)
    at org.wso2.carbon.dataservices.core.description.operation.Operation.execute(Operation.java:71)
    at org.wso2.carbon.dataservices.core.engine.DataService.invoke(DataService.java:592)
    at org.wso2.carbon.dataservices.core.engine.DSOMDataSource.execute(DSOMDataSource.java:99)
    at org.wso2.carbon.dataservices.core.engine.DSOMDataSource.serialize(DSOMDataSource.java:110)
    at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.llom.OMSourcedElementImpl.internalSerialize(OMSourcedElementImpl.java:691)
    at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.util.OMSerializerUtil.serializeChildren(OMSerializerUtil.java:563)
    at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.llom.OMElementImpl.internalSerialize(OMElementImpl.java:875)
    at org.apache.axiom.soap.impl.llom.SOAPEnvelopeImpl.serializeInternally(SOAPEnvelopeImpl.java:283)
    at org.apache.axiom.soap.impl.llom.SOAPEnvelopeImpl.internalSerialize(SOAPEnvelopeImpl.java:245)
    at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.llom.OMSerializableImpl.serializeAndConsume(OMSerializableImpl.java:193)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.SOAPMessageFormatter.writeTo(SOAPMessageFormatter.java:74)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.CommonsHTTPTransportSender.sendUsingOutputStream(CommonsHTTPTransportSender.java:409)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.CommonsHTTPTransportSender.invoke(CommonsHTTPTransportSender.java:286)
    at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.send(AxisEngine.java:443)
    at org.apache.axis2.receivers.AbstractInOutSyncMessageReceiver.invokeBusinessLogic(AbstractInOutSyncMessageReceiver.java:45)
    at org.apache.axis2.receivers.AbstractMessageReceiver.receive(AbstractMessageReceiver.java:110)
    at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.receive(AxisEngine.java:181)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.HTTPTransportUtils.processHTTPPostRequest(HTTPTransportUtils.java:172)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AxisServlet.doPost(AxisServlet.java:146)
    at org.wso2.carbon.core.transports.CarbonServlet.doPost(CarbonServlet.java:199)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:641)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ServletRegistration.handleRequest(ServletRegistration.java:90)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ProxyServlet.processAlias(ProxyServlet.java:111)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ProxyServlet.service(ProxyServlet.java:67)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    at org.wso2.carbon.bridge.BridgeServlet.service(BridgeServlet.java:164)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:304)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:240)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:164)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:462)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:164)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
    at org.wso2.carbon.server.CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.invoke(CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.java:154)
    at org.wso2.carbon.server.TomcatServer$1.invoke(TomcatServer.java:254)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:563)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:399)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProcessor.process(Http11NioProcessor.java:396)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11NioProtocol.java:356)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1534)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
[2012-06-13 12:42:08,106] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.dataservices.core.engine.DataService} -  DS Fault Message: Error in 'SQLQuery.processNormalQuery'
DS Code: DATABASE_ERROR
Source Data Service:-
Name: EmployeeService
Location: \EmployeeService.dbs
Description: N/A
Default Namespace: http://ws.wso2.org/dataservice
Current Request Name: findByEmployeeNameLike
Current Params: {Bind_name=S%}
Nested Exception:-
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingPreparedStatement cannot be cast to java.sql.CallableStatement

DS Fault Message: Error in 'SQLQuery.processNormalQuery'
DS Code: DATABASE_ERROR
Source Data Service:-
Name: EmployeeService
Location: \EmployeeService.dbs
Description: N/A
Default Namespace: http://ws.wso2.org/dataservice
Current Request Name: findByEmployeeNameLike
Current Params: {Bind_name=S%}
Nested Exception:-
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingPreparedStatement cannot be cast to java.sql.CallableStatement

    at org.wso2.carbon.dataservices.core.description.query.SQLQuery.processNormalQuery(SQLQuery.java:844)
    at org.wso2.carbon.dataservices.core.description.query.SQLQuery.runQuery(SQLQuery.java:2069)
    at org.wso2.carbon.dataservices.core.description.query.Query.execute(Query.java:252)
    at org.wso2.carbon.dataservices.core.engine.CallQuery.execute(CallQuery.java:185)
    at org.wso2.carbon.dataservices.core.engine.CallQueryGroup.execute(CallQueryGroup.java:110)
    at org.wso2.carbon.dataservices.core.description.operation.Operation.execute(Operation.java:71)
    at org.wso2.carbon.dataservices.core.engine.DataService.invoke(DataService.java:592)
    at org.wso2.carbon.dataservices.core.engine.DSOMDataSource.execute(DSOMDataSource.java:99)
    at org.wso2.carbon.dataservices.core.engine.DSOMDataSource.serialize(DSOMDataSource.java:110)
    at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.llom.OMSourcedElementImpl.internalSerialize(OMSourcedElementImpl.java:691)
    at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.util.OMSerializerUtil.serializeChildren(OMSerializerUtil.java:563)
    at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.llom.OMElementImpl.internalSerialize(OMElementImpl.java:875)
    at org.apache.axiom.soap.impl.llom.SOAPEnvelopeImpl.serializeInternally(SOAPEnvelopeImpl.java:283)
    at org.apache.axiom.soap.impl.llom.SOAPEnvelopeImpl.internalSerialize(SOAPEnvelopeImpl.java:245)
    at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.llom.OMSerializableImpl.serializeAndConsume(OMSerializableImpl.java:193)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.SOAPMessageFormatter.writeTo(SOAPMessageFormatter.java:74)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.CommonsHTTPTransportSender.sendUsingOutputStream(CommonsHTTPTransportSender.java:409)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.CommonsHTTPTransportSender.invoke(CommonsHTTPTransportSender.java:286)
    at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.send(AxisEngine.java:443)
    at org.apache.axis2.receivers.AbstractInOutSyncMessageReceiver.invokeBusinessLogic(AbstractInOutSyncMessageReceiver.java:45)
    at org.apache.axis2.receivers.AbstractMessageReceiver.receive(AbstractMessageReceiver.java:110)
    at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.receive(AxisEngine.java:181)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.HTTPTransportUtils.processHTTPPostRequest(HTTPTransportUtils.java:172)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AxisServlet.doPost(AxisServlet.java:146)
    at org.wso2.carbon.core.transports.CarbonServlet.doPost(CarbonServlet.java:199)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:641)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ServletRegistration.handleRequest(ServletRegistration.java:90)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ProxyServlet.processAlias(ProxyServlet.java:111)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ProxyServlet.service(ProxyServlet.java:67)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    at org.wso2.carbon.bridge.BridgeServlet.service(BridgeServlet.java:164)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:304)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:240)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:164)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:462)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:164)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
    at org.wso2.carbon.server.CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.invoke(CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.java:154)
    at org.wso2.carbon.server.TomcatServer$1.invoke(TomcatServer.java:254)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:563)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:399)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProcessor.process(Http11NioProcessor.java:396)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11NioProtocol.java:356)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1534)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingPreparedStatement cannot be cast to java.sql.CallableStatement
    at org.wso2.carbon.dataservices.core.description.query.SQLQuery.setStringValue(SQLQuery.java:1943)
    at org.wso2.carbon.dataservices.core.description.query.SQLQuery.setParamInPreparedStatement(SQLQuery.java:1411)
    at org.wso2.carbon.dataservices.core.description.query.SQLQuery.createProcessedPreparedStatement(SQLQuery.java:1380)
    at org.wso2.carbon.dataservices.core.description.query.SQLQuery.processNormalQuery(SQLQuery.java:802)
    ... 50 more
[2012-06-13 12:42:08,110] ERROR {org.apache.axis2.transport.http.CommonsHTTPTransportSender} -  DS Fault Message: Error in 'SQLQuery.processNormalQuery'
DS Code: DATABASE_ERROR
Source Data Service:-
Name: EmployeeService
Location: \EmployeeService.dbs
Description: N/A
Default Namespace: http://ws.wso2.org/dataservice
Current Request Name: findByEmployeeNameLike
Current Params: {Bind_name=S%}
Nested Exception:-
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingPreparedStatement cannot be cast to java.sql.CallableStatement

org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: DS Fault Message: Error in 'SQLQuery.processNormalQuery'
DS Code: DATABASE_ERROR
Source Data Service:-
Name: EmployeeService
Location: \EmployeeService.dbs
Description: N/A
Default Namespace: http://ws.wso2.org/dataservice
Current Request Name: findByEmployeeNameLike
Current Params: {Bind_name=S%}
Nested Exception:-
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingPreparedStatement cannot be cast to java.sql.CallableStatement

    at org.apache.axis2.AxisFault.makeFault(AxisFault.java:430)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.SOAPMessageFormatter.writeTo(SOAPMessageFormatter.java:78)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.CommonsHTTPTransportSender.sendUsingOutputStream(CommonsHTTPTransportSender.java:409)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.CommonsHTTPTransportSender.invoke(CommonsHTTPTransportSender.java:286)
    at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.send(AxisEngine.java:443)
    at org.apache.axis2.receivers.AbstractInOutSyncMessageReceiver.invokeBusinessLogic(AbstractInOutSyncMessageReceiver.java:45)
    at org.apache.axis2.receivers.AbstractMessageReceiver.receive(AbstractMessageReceiver.java:110)
    at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.receive(AxisEngine.java:181)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.HTTPTransportUtils.processHTTPPostRequest(HTTPTransportUtils.java:172)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AxisServlet.doPost(AxisServlet.java:146)
    at org.wso2.carbon.core.transports.CarbonServlet.doPost(CarbonServlet.java:199)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:641)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ServletRegistration.handleRequest(ServletRegistration.java:90)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ProxyServlet.processAlias(ProxyServlet.java:111)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ProxyServlet.service(ProxyServlet.java:67)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    at org.wso2.carbon.bridge.BridgeServlet.service(BridgeServlet.java:164)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:304)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:240)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:164)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:462)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:164)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
    at org.wso2.carbon.server.CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.invoke(CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.java:154)
    at org.wso2.carbon.server.TomcatServer$1.invoke(TomcatServer.java:254)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:563)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:399)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProcessor.process(Http11NioProcessor.java:396)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11NioProtocol.java:356)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1534)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Caused by: javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: DS Fault Message: Error in 'SQLQuery.processNormalQuery'
DS Code: DATABASE_ERROR
Source Data Service:-
Name: EmployeeService
Location: \EmployeeService.dbs
Description: N/A
Default Namespace: http://ws.wso2.org/dataservice
Current Request Name: findByEmployeeNameLike
Current Params: {Bind_name=S%}
Nested Exception:-
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingPreparedStatement cannot be cast to java.sql.CallableStatement

    at org.wso2.carbon.dataservices.core.engine.DSOMDataSource.execute(DSOMDataSource.java:105)
    at org.wso2.carbon.dataservices.core.engine.DSOMDataSource.serialize(DSOMDataSource.java:110)
    at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.llom.OMSourcedElementImpl.internalSerialize(OMSourcedElementImpl.java:691)
    at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.util.OMSerializerUtil.serializeChildren(OMSerializerUtil.java:563)
    at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.llom.OMElementImpl.internalSerialize(OMElementImpl.java:875)
    at org.apache.axiom.soap.impl.llom.SOAPEnvelopeImpl.serializeInternally(SOAPEnvelopeImpl.java:283)
    at org.apache.axiom.soap.impl.llom.SOAPEnvelopeImpl.internalSerialize(SOAPEnvelopeImpl.java:245)
    at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.llom.OMSerializableImpl.serializeAndConsume(OMSerializableImpl.java:193)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.SOAPMessageFormatter.writeTo(SOAPMessageFormatter.java:74)
    ... 35 more
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here find the .dbs file that I used,

```
<data name="DDD">   
<config id="ds1">      
  <property name="org.wso2.ws.dataservice.driver">oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver</property>      
  <property name="org.wso2.ws.dataservice.protocol">jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521/xe</property>      
  <property name="org.wso2.ws.dataservice.user">xxx</property>      
  <property name="org.wso2.ws.dataservice.password">xxx</property>
</config>   
<query id="q1" useConfig="ds1">      
  <sql>select EMPLOYEENUMBER  from employees where LASTNAME like :Bind_name</sql>      
  <result element="Entries" rowName="Entry">         
     <element name="EMPLOYEENUMBER" column="EMPLOYEENUMBER" xsdType="xs:string" />      
  </result>      
<param name="Bind_name" sqlType="STRING" />   
</query>   
<operation name="op1">      
  <call-query href="q1">         
     <with-param name="Bind_name" query-param="Bind_name" />      
  </call-query>   
</operation>
</data>
```

And the request is,

```
<p:op1 xmlns:p="http://ws.wso2.org/dataservice">
  <!--Exactly 1 occurrence-->
  <p:Bind_name>d%</p:Bind_name>
</p:op1>
```

It works fine as expected. Could you post your dbs file as well ?